# How do I force SSH to use password, not rsa key?

Tags: ssh, login, password

I set up an SSH key and changed my username in keeping with some [best practices](http://www.codelitt.com/blog/my-first-10-minutes-on-a-server-primer-for-securing-ubuntu/#fnref:1), having previously lost a pi installation after it was likely compromised via bruteforce. Unfortunately, it appears I also set up a password for my local SSH key, as I get the prompt `Enter your password for the SSH key "id_rsa"`. I've tried the passwords I could think of, and none work (`Permission denied (public key) error in Terminal).

I know I have saved the password I used when I first set up my modified user, so I tried [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/15141/63810) answer to ignore the key and use password instead. I got the same error from Terminal. How do I force key ignore and use password instead?

Comment: Have you removed the permission to use password authentication (PasswordAuthentication no`) from the ssh server configuration?

Comment: No, I currently can't access the pi via SSH - it's running headless in the office. Do I need to disable that? ... and so I'd guess that's a plug-in-kvm situation?

Comment: you need to enable password authentication (if disasbled, the only possible way may be to plug the SD Card in a Linux machine or a Windows with ext2fsd driver and edit the file)

Comment: So the headless -> headed option wouldn't do it? I thought that I could startx and go from there...

Comment: If you have a keyboard and a monitor, you could edit the file via sudo too.

Comment: @aastefanov: I was able to go from headless to headed and update that file. Thanks. If you make that an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the article, one of the things mentioned is disabling password login:

```
PasswordAuthentication no
```

Commenting the line or changing the value to `yes` permits password login again.

Comment: An explanation of all the options can be found in `man sshd_config`, BTW.